# template_include stop working on woocommerce update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

The following code is to override the Product Details page template, It was working since the last update on WooCommerce. Can anyone help me out on this, thanks in advance.

```
    add_filter('template_include', 'wpautomate_plugin_templates');
    function wpautomate_plugin_templates( $template )
    {   
        $plugin_path='';
        $reflector = new ReflectionClass('Ze_Single_Product_Layout');
        $file_name=plugin_dir_path($reflector->getFileName());
        $plugin_path=$file_name;
        $post_types = array('product');
        $template_id=get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_product_layout', true );
        if (is_singular('product') && !empty($template_id))
        {
            //render custom template  for single product
            $template = $plugin_path . 'template/woo-single-page.php';
        }
        return $template;           

    }//end of function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call this filter

```
add_filter('template_include', 'wpautomate_plugin_templates');
```

with **init** action hook

```
add_action('init','load_custom_template_woo');
function load_custom_template_woo(){
  add_filter('template_include', 'wpautomate_plugin_templates');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to set the priory for the hook callback greater than 10, like this

```
// priority = 11
add_action('template_include', 'wpautomate_plugin_templates', 11);
```